# Twitter notification count via python

Tags: python, twitter, notifications, twitter-oauth

I was just wondering if there is a method to get the notification count from twitter using python. I checked a method that allows me to check whether someone has mentioned me in their tweet. So is there a function from the twitter api to get the notification count?

Comment: What does the API documentation say?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I checked it and didn't find anything useful, i saw a list of methods but none of them deals with notifications. I doubt there is no method for that. https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

Comment: @nick28 Simply going to the source and searching for "notification" yields 26 results... https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/source/browse/twitter.py

Comment: FYI, you only have to click "next" 5 times on that search to find your answer, don't have to go through all 26 ;)

Comment: @Ngenator i think you mean the GetNotifications(self)? I will try that method and check it out :) Thanks man!

Comment: @Ngenator sorry for my noob questions, but how do i call the GetNotifications method? I called other methods by api.(method name).
And what is the "self" argument? Sorry for these questions but i'm new to python and the social apps :)